# Build a data object in node/express and pass object to render template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

Got a noob question here... but first, a bit of background info...

I've started coding an application with Express JS, and though I'm getting the hang of it little by little, I've hit a brick wall...

I have a CodeIgniter background, and in CI you build a $data variable in your controller with all the data that you need to pass to the page that you will render.

So i'm trying to do the same thing in Express... but I'm failing to see how to properly do this.

For example,

I have this piece of code in a file called 'routes.js':

```
//when you navigate to domain.com/test
app.get('/test', function(req, res)
{
    //object where i want to store all my data
    var data = {};

    //dynamically get the navigation menu
    navigation_model.get_menu(function(err, result){

            if(err) throw err;

            //add the result, which is an object, to the data obj
            data.navigation = result;
    });


    content_model.findAll(function(err, result){

            if(err) throw err;

            //add the result, which is an object, to the data obj
            data.content = result;
    });

    //page that i want to send the data to 
    res.render('test_view',{data: this.data});

});
```

The problem that I'm having though, is that do to the async nature of Node, by the time I render out the page, my 'data' object still has not received the data from the models...

Questions:

1. so what is the best way to get the data into the 'data' obj?
2. do I have to nest code inside callback functions, inside more callback functions until my data obj has received the data? (Feels counter-productive)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you don't need to nest, but you do need to wait for everything to arrive before you can ship it (darn physics). you will end up calling render from a callback, not from the get function body...

Answer (score 1):

The reason data is null is because the functions getMenu & findAll are async, i.e. the render call is happening before getMenu & findAll are able to complete its executions and populate the approprivate values in data.

One way of fixing it is to call the 2nd function in the callback of the first and so on.

```
navigation_model.get_menu(function(err, result){

    if(err) throw err;

    //add the result, which is an object, to the data obj
    data.navigation = result;

    content_model.findAll(function(err, result){

            if(err) throw err;

            //add the result, which is an object, to the data obj
            data.content = result;

            res.render('test_view',{data: this.data});
    });

 });
```

A better approch would be to use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library's parellel or waterfall methods to run the geMenu & findAll in prallel or one after the other by using waterfall and then call the render method.